# Set session variable with ajax call and refresh partial

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a ***Bootstrap Dropdown Button***. The list should have links that, when pressed, set a session state variable. The only page update I would like to happen is to render the ***Dropdown*** again, so the selected item appears as the header.

The ***Dropdown*** itself is rendered as a ***Partial View*** by a call to ***Child Action***

```
public PartialViewResult SessionStateVariableSelector()
{
    string stateVariable = Session["theStateVariable"] as string;

    StateVariableCollectionViewModel model = GetThisFromSomewhere();

    model.SelectedStateVariable = stateVariable ?? string.Empty;

    return PartialView("_sessionStateVariableSelector", model);
}
```

I initially had two ideas as how to do this.

A) `Ajax.Beginform` surrounding the ***Dropdown*** that posts to the same action. That way I would do a `UpdateTargetId` that updates the ***Dropdown*** with a new selected variable.

I just have no idea how to do the `AutoPostBack` using the ***Bootstrap*** theme. I wanted to get the same behavior as when using `<a>` inside the ***Dropdown*** list.

Could I intercept the `<a>` ***href*** as a ***postback*** from the AJAX call?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SetFund", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "theSelector", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right" id="theSelector">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    @if(string.IsNullOrEmpty( Model.SelectedStateVariable))
                    {
                        Please select....
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = Model.SelectedStateVariable })" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    }
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                            <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = item.Id })" alt="@item.Name" class="img-responsive" />
                        </li>
                        }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

B) Set each list element as a `<a>` with a ***href*** to some action the sets the state and somehow refreshes the partial as part of the result. I have no idea if this is possible.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right" id="theSelector">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                @if(string.IsNullOrEmpty( Model.SelectedStateVariable))
                {
                    Please select....
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = Model.SelectedStateVariable })" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                }
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("SetStateVariable", new { Id = item.Id })">
                            <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = item.Id })" alt="@item.Name" class="img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am really new to ***ASP.NET MVC*** and Web programming.

**EDIT**

I think all these answers below are in some way correct and each one of them adds something towards a workable solution. I picked the one that gave me AngularJS way as that is what I went with in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JQuery way:**

I like to use the jquery `.load()` method for ***Ajax Partial View*** refresh actions.

Let's say that your partial is encapsulated in a div (it could just as well be a span):

```
<div id="divSessionStateVariableSelector">
     @Html.RenderAction("SessionStateVariableSelector","DropDownController");
</div>
```

When your page first renders, you would get your "Default" behavior. Let's assume that the id of your rendered Dropdown button is `"ddbSessionStateVariableSelector"`. The name is only important because we will be binding a jquery event action against the name. Could just as easily be done with a class...

Next, create an event listener that reloads your partial upon ***click event***, passing the selection text as parameter to your partial view's child action:

```
<script>
$(".yourUlClassName li a").click(function() {
    $('#divSessionStateVariableSelector')
              .load('/DropDownController/SessionStateVariableSelector/' 
                     + $(this).text());

});
</script>
```

**Important:** change your partial child action signature to take an `id` as string. I'm working with the assumption that you use the "Default" route and are not interested in creating a new one.

```
public PartialViewResult 
           SessionStateVariableSelector(string id="{Default Value}")
```

---

**AngularJS way**

Even easier (but outside your range of question) use a binding framework like Angularjs to simply create a binding in your partial using the input.

It means learning a little extra (maybe a lot), but it would be a very simple implementation within your partial markup

```
<div ng-controller="SessionStateVariableSelectorController">

{{ SessionStateVariableSelector ||

<select ng-model="SessionStateVariableSelector" ... >

</div>
```

and some a little included javascript code:

```
<script>
function SessionStateVariableSelectorController($scope) {
$scope.SessionStateVariableSelector="Default Value";
  };
</script>
```

Comment: What would the selection event be? If I put it like you did the event would fire as soon as I press the button that expands the Dropdown list. I want it to fire when we select from the list.

Comment: @IngóVals, you're right, I wrote that out without thinking. it should be on `change` event. I'll change my answer to reflect.

Comment: But won't that only work with a `<select>` tag? In bootstrap a dropdown list is just a collapsed `<ul>` with button inside. I'm trying to find a way to use that like a `<select>`.

Comment: @IngóVals, riiiight... I knew there was a reason why i originally went with click event. it is a click event against a css class : `$(".yourUlClassName li a").click`

Comment: Ok I feel like I'm getting somewhere but not there yet. First off load doesn't seem to work properly for some reason. I see the request go off and the response looks good. But it doesn't get injected. The dropdown just disappears.

Comment: Ok not sure what I managed to change to get it to work. I also changed the JS to `+ $(this).find('#item_Id').val());` to get the hidden id number. Now a single problem left. If I store the script in the scripts section it won't get reapplied after the action. Do I have to store it inside the partial. Isn't dumping a script just anywhere bad?

Comment: @IngóVals, good question. No, it shouldn't make a difference about having the JS refs inside the partial. It all renders as 1 page. I suspect that the binding may have to be re-executed... Now question is how to make that happen...

Comment: @IngóVals, if you look at my 2nd suggestion, I suspect thats what should happen with JQuery. Seems all you really need to update is the text, not reload the dropdown. If we change the approach that way, no need to rebind the event handler.

Comment: You mean the AngularJS one? Currently this is a old school Asp.Net MVC project. Can I use AngularJS in good manner without using things like Routing that I would like for the MVC framework to handle?

And I actually have images and not text but I guess the same thing should apply.

Comment: absolutely you can. the example I gave you can use 1 aspect of angular. But really, I mean we should do this with JQuery. The real call back should NOT reload your drop-down. If I understand you correctly, we should simply re-write the label for it with the selected value. In other words, if the text is all that should change, why reload the drodown-button control and change it's bindings?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do but maybe something like this will help you:

```
var replaceDDL = function (ddlValue) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SessionStateVariableSelector", "YourController")',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "ddlValue": ddlValue
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#yourDDLId').replaceWith(response);
            $('#yourDDLId li a').click(function() { replaceDDL($(this).text()); });
        }
    });
};

$('#yourDDLId li a').click(function() { replaceDDL($(this).text()); });


public PartialViewResult SessionStateVariableSelector(string ddlValue)
{
    ....
    return PartialView("_sessionStateVariableSelector", model);
}
```

I created a method to call your controller and get the `partialView` with your ddl when you select an option from your ddl.

Comment: Hi, I currently do not know much javascript. But what would trigger the change function? In Bootstrap the Dropdown is represented by a `<ul>` tag and not a `<select>`

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it is correct but others were correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

For first time your dropdown will have value with default loading.
but when any update happen you need to reload the partial view again.
so your html will

```
<form><div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" id="theSelector">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            @if(string.IsNullOrEmpty( Model.SelectedStateVariable))
            {
                Please select....
            }
            else
            {
                <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = Model.SelectedStateVariable })" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="caret"></span>
            }
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:setState(@item.Id);">
                        <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Resource", new { id = item.Id })" alt="@item.Name" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you need to define javascript method setState(Id)

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
   function setSate(Id)
    {
    $.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("SetStateVariable")'+'?Id='+Id,
    type:'get'
    }).done(function(data){
    $("form").load('@Url.Action("SessionStateVariableSelector")');

    });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it can resolve your problem :)

Comment: The '<a href="javascript:setState(@item.Id);">' was a thing I didn't know beforehand. I upvoted your answer as it is correct but others were correct as well.